# Searching in Chrome results in search file being downloaded instead of loading the results

Tags: google-chrome

When I search Google with Google chrome (version 24) and type my phrase in Google text box search result appear fine

But when I changed it t o(phrase), instead of load the result with my new query, Chrome downloads a file named "search". Keep trying the the same file gets downloaded

[image: google chrome download]

And i must click on search button again for results to appear

Comment: Seems like it should stop if you clean your history and cookie, b/c Chrome remembers all your moves in the Internet and actually it should be helpfull for you making your last moves faster to find. You should go to the Chrome settings and try to change some of them (seems like Personal Data section containg them).

Comment: @Daria i do that. clean all history s and all cookies (two days later) but now problem also here and search(40) downloaded

Comment: @Daria im edit setting and check the box in setting enable instant search but now have same problem and instead of search , aslo a file downloaded again

Comment: what's the default search option?

Comment: me and my friend understand the problem occurred from the extension that  we want to disable them step by step...

Comment: FastestChrome is an extension that me and my friend install it and when disable it all thing is corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possibly due to a chrome extension you might be using, "[Fastest Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fastestchrome-browse-fast/mmffncokckfccddfenhkhnllmlobdahm?hl=en)". Try disabling the plugin or the search feature.